# export to Excel by PHPExcel and Codeigniter and Ajax

Tags: php, ajax, codeigniter, phpexcel

I want to have xls export by PHPExcel and use Codeigniter and AJAX, But I dont get any File, Please Help me

HTML Code for button:

```
<button class="buttonExcel" id="ButtonExcel" onclick="getExcel()" ></button>
```

My AJAX code is running good but dont create any file for me:

```
<script>
function getExcel()
    {
        $.ajax({
                       url:'<?=base_url();?>tops/posts/create_result',
                       destroy: true,
                       type: 'POST',
                       data: '',
                       beforeSend: function() {
                          $("#ButtonExcel").removeClass("buttonExcel");
                          $("#ButtonExcel").addClass("buttonExcel-getExcel");
                          $("#ButtonExcel").blur();
                       },
                       success: function(response){


                               window.open('<?=base_url();?>tops/posts/create_result','_blank');
                    },
                        error: function(){
                            alert("error when get data");

                        }
                });
        }

</script>
```

My Contoroler running good without ajax:

```
 public function create_result()
   {

         set_time_limit(600);
         $this->load->model('tops/Posts_model');
         $list = $this->Posts_model->create_result(); 


         require(APPPATH."third_party/PHPExcel-1.8/Classes/PHPExcel.php");
         require(APPPATH."third_party/PHPExcel-1.8/Classes/PHPExcel/Writer/Excel5.php");

         $objPHPExcel = new PHPExcel();

         $objPHPExcel->getProperties()->setCreator("");
         $objPHPExcel->getProperties()->setLastModifiedBy("");
         $objPHPExcel->getProperties()->setTitle("");
         $objPHPExcel->getProperties()->setSubject("");
         $objPHPExcel->getProperties()->setDescription("");

         $objPHPExcel->setActiveSheetIndex(0);

         $sheet = $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet();

         $sheet->setCellValue("A1","text");
         $sheet->setCellValue("B1","time");
         $sheet->setCellValue("C1","date");
         $sheet->setCellValue("D1","type");
         $sheet->setCellValue("E1","view");

         $row = 2;

         foreach ($list as $key => $value)
         {

             $sheet->setCellValue("A".$row,$value['MsgText']);
             $sheet->setCellValue("B".$row,$value['MsgTime']);
             $sheet->setCellValue("C".$row,$value['MsgDate']);
             $sheet->setCellValue("D".$row,$value['MsgType']);
             $sheet->setCellValue("E".$row,$value['CountView']);
             $row++;
             }

         $filename = "Task-Exportet-on-".date("Y-m-d-H-i-s").".xls";
         $sheet->setTitle("Task-Overview");

         header('Content-Type: application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet'); //mime type
        header('Content-Disposition: attachment;filename="'.$filename.'"'); //tell browser what's the file name
        header('Cache-Control: max-age=0');


        $objWriter = PHPExcel_IOFactory::createWriter($objPHPExcel, 'Excel5');  
                //force user to download the Excel file without writing it to server's HD
        $objWriter->save('php://output');
        set_time_limit(30);
        exit;
    }
```

Comment: will you post ans for this. I fall in the same problem and not getting any solution.

Answer (score -2, accepted):

I fixed this problem with replace this headers to older headers in my controller:

```
header("Pragma: public");
header("Expires: 0");
header("Cache-Control: must-revalidate, post-check=0, pre-check=0");
header("Content-Type: application/force-download");
header("Content-Type: application/octet-stream");
header("Content-Type: application/download");;
header("Content-Disposition: attachment;filename=$filename");
```

Answer (score 0):

Code Seems and working fine, only the reason you are not able to get file is to allow Pop-up window in your browser.

Comment: This issue does not relate to POP-UP, But I active POP-UP and when I run this page, Error section of AJAX code is running and show to me   1 alert that located this in error ajax, and in browser console for create_result() function just show : ÐÏà¡±á;þÿ ÔþÿÿÿÕÖ×ØÙÚÛÜÝÞßàÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿ